# Search and replace on specific lines in Vim

Tags: vim, replace

I can use

```
:5,12s/foo/bar/g
```

to search for `foo` and replace it by `bar` between lines 5 and 12. How can I do that only in line 5 and 12 (and not in the lines in between)?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Vim has special regular expression atoms that match in certain lines, columns, etc.; you can use them (possibly in addition to the range) to limit the matches:

```
:5,12s/\(\%5l\|\%12l\)foo/bar/g
```

See `:help /\%l`

Comment: A more complicated way than I expected but answers my question perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 75):

You can do the substitution on line 5 and repeat it with minimal effort on line 12:

```
:5s/foo/bar
:12&
```

As pointed out by Ingo, `:&` forgets your flags. Since you are using `/g`, the correct command would be `:&&`:

```
:5s/foo/bar/g
:12&&
```

See `:help :&` and friends.

Comment: +1 for putting the obscure `:&` to use. If there are flags (`s/../../g`), one has to use `:&&`, though...

Comment: @IngoKarkat, to be fair, I think `\(\%5l\|\%12l\)` is more obscure than `:&`

Comment: `:&` is not obscure at all. Maybe read some vim docs.

Comment: @NeilG, Ingo has a huge track record and is really not the kind of person you need to nudge toward the docs. `:&` is certainly documented but it is rarely, if ever, mentioned in the average Medium post or YouTube video and, sadly, vimmers rarely go beyond those unless forced to. It is not even mentioned in Vim's own introductory material. In that sense, `:&` definitely deserves the "obscure" epithet.

Comment: Given such a track record I'm not sure why he would label `:&` as obscure. It's somewhat a matter of personal experience, but the brevity of the syntax, that the feature is provided on a single character, goes some way to objectively determine that it's not really appropriate for the "obscure" list. As @doubleDown gently but firmly exposes in his comment. I think Ingo is obviously wrong on this one. I wouldn't put any store by Medium posts, still less any videos! There is no quality to speak of in contemporary tech blogging. I hark back further. I'm watching the wisdom drain out of the world.

Comment: `:&` is not obscure to me, because I learned Vim properly, with the user manual and then `changes.txt` and all. I presume Ingo's journey was similar, as well as yours. For *us* those things are not obscure: they are more or less clearly documented and we use/suggest them when appropriate. But that's *us*, and we are in the minority. Many Vimmers sadly don't care about all that as they get all their "knowledge" from blogs and videos and tweets and crap like that. `:&` is obscure to *them*.

Answer (score 26):

You could always add a `c` to the end. This will ask for confirmation for each and every match.

```
:5,12s/foo/bar/gc
```

Comment: This can be a nightmare if there are a lot of matches in between lines 5 and 12 (keep in mind that there's a `g` flag in play)

Comment: @doubleDown This isn't meant to be a universal solution (where there are many possible candidates), but in most cases do you really thing pressing `n` 5 or 6 times is any more onerous than adding `\(\%5l\|\%12l\)` to the substitute statement?

Comment: I find this useful, I wanted to change every other line, this would have been faster than what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 12):

Interesting question. Seems like there's only range selection and no multiple line selection:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges

However, if you have something special on line 5 and 12, you could use the `:g` operator. If your file looks like this (numbers only for reference):

```
 1     line one
 2     line one
 3     line one
 4     line one
 5     enil one
 6     line one
 7     line one
 8     line one
 9     line one
10     line one
11     line one
12     enil one
```

And you want to replace `one` by `eno` on the lines where there's `enil` instead of `line`:

```
:g/enil/s/one/eno/
```

Comment: this is actually assuming *a lot*

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ed` - a line oriented text editor with similar commands to vi and vim. It probably predates vi and vim.

In a script (using a here document which processes input till the EndCommand marker) it would look like:

```
ed file <<EndCommands
    5
    s/foo/bar/g
    7
    s/foo/bar/g
    wq
EndCommands
```

Obviously, the ed commands can be used on the command line also.

Comment: I don't see an advantage over the `vim` alternative.

Comment: And the same can be done with Vim, too; the numbers can actually be put before the `:s`, but there's still the duplication of the `:s` command (which romainl's solution avoids).

Comment: My view was the user may wanted to select a great deal more than two lines for editing. In that case a non-interactive approach could have been of interest - which AFAIK cannot be done with vim.

Comment: Oh, Vim can do that (e.g. in "Ex" mode), but you're right that another tool should be prefered over an interactive editor. My preference would be `sed`, though...