# Search and delete particular word in vi editor mode

Tags: unix, vim

I have 100 lines file with name "data.txt" 
In this in 2nd line and 10th line having a word "rahul" Rest of lines also have some random lines but i want to delete this particular word (or lines) only 2 and 10 lines  from this file using vi editor in single command

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319557/search-and-replace-in-vim-in-specific-lines . In your case: `%s/\(\%2l\|\%10l\)rahul//g`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace in vim in specific lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319557/search-and-replace-in-vim-in-specific-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Basically follow these steps

1. vim data.txt
2. :g/rahul/d

[vim search and delete](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Delete_all_lines_containing_a_pattern)

Comment: But it not showing particular lines deleting which I want,  my pattern contain more than 10 lines randomly, but i want to delete line no.  2nd and 10th which contain this pattern